# How to get the gradients of loss with respect to activations in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In the `cifar10` example, the gradients of loss with respect to parameters can be computed as follows:

```
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
for grad, var in grads_and_vars:
    # ...
```

Is there any way to get the gradients of loss with respect to activations (not the parameters)， and watch them in Tensorboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`tf.gradients()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#gradients) function to compute the gradient of any scalar tensor with respect to any other tensor (assuming the gradients are defined for all of the ops between those two tensors):

```
activations = ...
loss = f(..., activations)  # `loss` is some function of `activations`.

grad_wrt_activations, = tf.gradients(loss, [activation])
```

Visualizing this in TensorBoard is tricky in general, since `grad_wrt_activation` is (typically) a tensor with the same shape as `activation`. Adding a [`tf.histogram_summary()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#histogram_summary) op is probably the easiest way to visualize

```
# Adds a histogram of `grad_wrt_activations` to the graph, which will be logged
# with the other summaries, and shown in TensorBoard.
tf.histogram_summary("Activation gradient", grad_wrt_activations)
```

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I want.

Comment: Does the graph compute the gradients twice when both opt.compute_gradients() and tf.gradients() are used? Is there any additional computational cost?

Comment: The graph will contain two copies of the gradient-related nodes if you call both `opt.compute_gradients()` and `tf.gradients()`, but the back-end should remove these nodes during common subexpression elimination (if not, that would be a bug).